# Problema con tabla HTML

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de imprimir una tabla HTML desde un archivo PHP. Sí me detecta los registros, pero las celdas se quedan en blanco. ¿Cómo le podría hacer para que se vean cada uno de los registros en la tabla?

Les dejo el código donde creo que está el error:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchUser)) {
        $data = $row[0].'||'.$row[1].'||'.$row[2].'||'.$row[3].'||'.$row[4];
        $table.=
        '<tbody><tr>
        <th style="padding-top: 10px;"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></th>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;"><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;"><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
        <td>
        <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-1 mx-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUpdateUser" onclick="getData(<?php echo $data; ?>);"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteUser(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>);"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr></tbody>
        ';
    }

?>
```

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Tienes error en como agregas los datos `$row`, no puedes abrir `<?php` dentro de otro. Deberías solo concatenar las variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes abrir otro `<?php` dentro de uno, es necesario cerrarlo.

Como trabajas con una cadena de texto puedes concatenar la variables como lo hacen en `$data`

```php
<?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchUser)) {
            $data = $row[0].'||'.$row[1].'||'.$row[2].'||'.$row[3].'||'.$row[4];
            $table.=
            '<tbody><tr>
            <th style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[0].'</th>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[1].'</td>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[2].'</td>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[3].'</td>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[4].'></td>
            <td>
            <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-1 mx-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUpdateUser" onclick="getData('.$data.');"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteUser('.$row[0].');"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr></tbody>
            ';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Excelente, sí me funcionó amigo. Ya lo había intentado así pero mi error era que ponía punto y coma '. $row[4]; .' y ya veo que no se debe poner jaja

Comment: Si, en ocasiones se puede confundir porque en `PHP` se termina con `;`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda bro :)